# How to access both IIS and Geoserver at port 80 from outside the production environment?

Tags: iis, port, geoserver

At production server, IIS and GeoServer are installed. I can access IIS at port 80 From out side the production environment. i also want to access GeoServer at the same port 80 from out side of production environment, Like http://92.108.64.13:80/geoserver/web/. But, i could not access GeoServer at port 80.

Is it possible to access both IIS and Geoserver at port 80 ? Normally, Geoserver runs on different port, valid range is (1024 to 65535). Actually I do not want to open any other port for accessing GeoServer. Is there any solution available for accessing both Geoserver and IIS at port 80 ?

need for useful suggestion for solving this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You can try one of the two approaches:
1. Oracle provides a WebLogic plugin (it is basically an ISAPI extension for IIS) which can be used to configure forwarding requests from IIS to WebLogic. Apparently this also works with Jetty, which is the default java container that GeoServer comes with. Getting it to work properly on Windows 2008 is not very straightforward. Probably easier on previous versions of IIS (IIS 6).
2. Use URL Rewrite module from IIS.Net http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

I am trying to get the exact same implementation that you are doing. So I will let you know what works for me. I have tried approach 1 but not quite got it working as I want.